# Is the WSDL any longer needed once the Java classes have been generated using it?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, intellij-idea, wsdl

I've just started working on SOAP and I have very little idea about the role of WSDL in it other than the fact that it has the definition of classes used for communication with a SOAP Web service.

I have this WSDL that I generated my Java code from using IntelliJ's **Generate Java code from WSDL**. Now the WSDL doc has the following piece of code in which I'm setting my client id and client password

```
<soap:address location="https://www.somewebservice.com/testEvn/TestService?client_id=XXXX-XXX-XXX&amp;client_password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

When I host my application on some site, I don't want to put the WSDL document in there as it has the above-mentioned sensitive information. So my question is, if I remove the WSDL from the entire project, will the classes and the methods still work?

Does the WSDL need to exist anymore once the classes have been generated?
What is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will need cause next time when you are going to build your project then it will take the reference for regenerating those classes, cause when you are running your build it will clean means delete all generated resources from your project directory and then regenerated those classes. I am considering maven as a build tool here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're downloading your WSDL from a URL, you could also just download it (just copy to a new file and change the file ending to .wsdl) once and store it locally somewhere in your project (e.g. in src/main/resources or target) and just access it from a file path. That way, you could prevent the URL from being "leaked".

But should the WSDL for the web service change, your program won't be able to access it if you just stored it locally, therefore it might be better to have a WSDL URL.

In any case, the WSDL is needed for any (re-)build of the project (e.g. mvn clean install) as classes are generated anew.